# Python - GPG Encrypt From Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, encryption, gnupg, windows-task-scheduler

I have a simple python script that is GPG encrypting a file using the GNUPG library. The script works as expected when I execute it manually in Visual Studio code. It also works in windows task scheduler as long as the option "Run only when user is logged on" is enabled.

As soon as I use the option "Run whether user is logged on or not", the script does not execute successfully.

This is what gets returned in the script:

```
ok:  False
status:  invalid recipient
```

I am using my same login credentials in Task Scheduler so I'm not sure what's happening here. I have tried executing the python script via a batch file and powershell script and get the same behavior.

Here is the block of code although I think it is more user account related than Python related.

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU\\GnuPG')
with open('F:\\Data\\Testing\\test.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.encrypt_file(
        f, recipients=['TestRecipient'],
        always_trust=True,
        output='F:\\Data\\Testing\\test.xlsx.gpg')
```